# Small caps for siunitx units

Tags: siunitx, small-caps

The Economist style guide suggests typesetting capital units and prefixes, except for temperatures, in small caps.

How can I achieve this with siunitx? Should I redefine them all with `\DeclareSIUnit` and `\DeclareSIPrefix`?

[image]

Comment: Please tell us which SI units you're most interested in. No point in redefining the appearance of units that you're not going to use, right?

Comment: By the way, the style guidelines of The Economist for scientific units can be rather problematic in practice, especially because `m` can mean "meter", "milli", and "mega". For instance, these guidelines do not produce a good outcome for "millimeter." Note also that these guidelines are frankly inconsistent as they prescribe lowercase letters for some prefixes (e.g., "milli", "kilo" and, presumably, "centi"), but not for others ( "mega", "giga", "tera",  and "peta"). In short, I'd stick with the standard lettering -- which, happily, is fully implemented by the `siunitx` package.

Comment: The fundamental issue here that that the people writing the guide have interpreted unit symbols a abbreviations: The Economist generally uses small caps for abbreviations. However, they are not: they are mathematical symbols in the same way that _x_ for a variable is. That doesn't help at the technical level but does explain why things look frankly strange.

Comment: @Mico I'm interested in e.g. MHz and (`\textsc{mhz}`) and GPa (`\textsc{gp}a`?). I agree using "1m" to mean a million is ambiguous, I'm just interested in the unit (and prefix) part of the style guide.

Comment: @JosephWright Any idea why this incorrect reasoning would be part of their style guide? I'm reading the 2015 edition and don't have their paper newspaper, it could have been updated since.

Comment: @Anna It's a common misconception - the same reason you find people asking for `10-m` in adverbial situations (again wrong). Also, _The Economist_ doesn't have a lot of  hard-core unit usage, so it's likely they've take a desire for style for the odd unit usage over mathematical clarity.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you for sharing your insights!